# Использование оператора spread

Tags: javascript

Результатом работы кода, показанного ниже является массив из элементов от 1 до 4.

```js
let mass = [...new Array(4)].map((_,i) => i+1);
console.log(mass);
```

Но сам результат не особо важен, я не могу понять из-за чего при следующем коде, когда способ задания массива немного изменяется, массив остаётся пустым и не заполняется должным (в моём неверном понимании) образом.

```js
let mass = new Array(4).map((_,i) => i+1);
console.log(mass);
```

Comment: [Метод map вызывает переданную функцию callback один раз для каждого элемента, в порядке их появления и конструирует новый массив из результатов её вызова. Функция callback вызывается только для индексов массива, имеющих присвоенные значения, включая undefined. Она не вызывается для пропущенных элементов массива (то есть для индексов, которые никогда не были заданы, которые были удалены или которым никогда не было присвоено значение.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в поведении функции `map` для разреженных массивов - массивов с элементами, которые *никогда не были назначены*. Для этих элементов callback, поданный в функцию `map`, не вызывается.

```js
var a = [];
a.length = 4;
let mass = a.map((_,i) => { console.log("map callback", _, i); return i+1; });
console.log("mass", mass);
console.log("no map callback was called");

console.log("=".repeat(20));

var a1 = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];
let mass1 = a1.map((_,i) => { console.log("map callback", _, i); return i+1; });
console.log("mass1", mass1);
```